# How to run lb/lb4 loopback cli 3 or 4 command not found windows10 1903, after installing successfully

Tags: command-line-interface, loopback

I'm making a new app using loopback`cli. I have installed`cli(v4)`successfully with the command`"npm install -g @loopback/cli"`. I am on windows 10 1903. The problem is,`lb4`isn't working. It shows the error that`lb4` command isn't recognized as the internal or external command. What should I have to do to solve this problem?

Comment: Can you set nodejs path in environment variable

Comment: It is done already.